# Magnetic field inside infinite slab

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have a short magnetostatics question. Given a thick slab extending from $z=-a$ to $z=a$ (and infinite in the $x$ and $y$ directions) carries a uniform volume current $\vec{J} = J\hat{x}$, why does it follow that $B = 0$ when $z=0$?

Comment: $B\propto z$...hence $B=0$ when $z=0$

Comment: @PrasadMani How do you know that $B \propto z $ without knowing that $B = 0$ at $z = 0$? I only get that by first knowing that $B = 0$ at $z = 0$ and then applying Amperes law.

Comment: Actually, i had to track back on this one. Since by applying ampere's law, i got $B.2l$=$\mu_0 l z J$, then you see how $B \propto z$, meaning there is a discontinuity of $B$ at $z=0$ plane. Hence you cannot cover your amperian loop to go from positive z to negative z symmetrically. You have to break it down  such that it either covers some part above $z=0$ or some part below it. But hands down, the answer by Jeannette posted is much better than what i did.

Answer (score 2):

Symmetry. The whole system is symmetric under, by example, the mirror symmetry $z \rightarrow -z$, hence $ \vec{B} \rightarrow -\vec{B}$ under that symmetry ($B$ is a pseudo-vector) . So at $z=0$, $\vec{B} = - \vec{B}$

Comment: And the reason for that apparent symmetry is? Because there is no such kind of symmetry in the current density

Comment: @Jeannette Thanks for your answer, but there seems to be a missing argument when you go from $\vec{B} \to -\vec{B}$ under the symmetry $\implies$ at $z = 0$, $\vec{B} = -\vec{B}$. How do you justify the last step?

Comment: Well, $\vec{B}(z) = -\vec{B}(-z)$, hence $\vec{B}(0) = -\vec{B}(0)$.

Comment: @PrasadMani the current distribution is conserved under $z \rightarrow -z$ if I'm not mistaken ? You get the exact same system under that transformation.

Comment: @Jeannette Yeah but what I'm saying is that by symmetry we get that, $\vec{B}(z) = - \vec{B}(-z)$ for $z > 0$ not necessarily for $z = 0$? So at $z=0$ I think you might need some further argument? Do you see what my concern is? So for example, if we were considering a real valued function $f$ which satisfied this symmetry argument $f(z) = -f(-z)$ for $z > 0$ then if say $f$ was continuous then we could state that $f(0) = -f(0)$ which implies $f(0) = 0$, but if we didn't assume $f$ was continuous then we couldn't state that.

Comment: @Alex The $xy$ plane would be the set of fixed points of the reflection mapping. So the reflection mapping is a mapping which includes points $z = 0$ in it's domain. See wiki entry 'reflection' for good discussion on this topic. So I think Jeannette's explanation holds in this regard. You don't require anything further as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, symmetry. The current density is symmetric under a rotation by $\pi$ about the $x$ axis, which means that the magnetic field at the middle of the slab also needs to be symmetric:
$$
B_y = -B_y \quad\text{and}\quad B_z=-B_z,
$$
i.e. $\vec B = B_x \hat x$ is along the $x$ axis.

This $x$ component should intuitively cancel, since the field is along the $y$ axis everywhere. I'm not sure this can be proved by symmetry, but if nothing else it follows from the Biot-Savart expression for the magnetic field:
$$
\vec B(\vec r) = \int \frac{J(\vec r')\mathrm dV \:\hat x\times(\vec r-\vec r')}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^3}
$$
implies that $\vec B\cdot \hat x\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the differential for the Biot-Savart law: $$d\textbf B=\frac{\mu _0 J dV}{4\pi} \hat x\times \frac{\textbf r-\textbf r'}{|\textbf r-\textbf r'|^3}$$

One sees right away that $\textbf B$ is perpendicular to $\hat x$, so $B_x=0$.

The next claim is that symmetry causes $B_z=0$. Using infinitesimal $d\textbf B$, choose any point $\textbf r$. Then, for any point $\textbf r_+$ in the structure forming the infinitesimal field element, there is a symmetric $\textbf r_-$ for which $dB_z^+=-dB_z^-$. I have graphed a few examples:

[image: z-symmetry]

Once you convince yourself that integrating all of the $d\textbf B$ would yield $B_z=0$, then you can use Ampere's Law: $$\mu _0J\hat x=\nabla \times \textbf B=-\frac{\partial B_y}{\partial z}\hat x$$

Integrating this yields $B_y=-\mu _0Jz+C$ for $-a\leq z\leq a$. I felt justified in tossing the uniform component $+C$ since there is no coiling of the electric current, and $\textbf B=-\mu _0Jz \hat y$